# org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: font without font-triplet

Tags: java, apache-fop

I am getting intermittent error while generating PDF using FOP.

```
 org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: font without font-triplet
    at org.apache.fop.util.LogUtil.handleError(LogUtil.java:42)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.DefaultFontConfig$ParserHelper.parseFonts(DefaultFontConfig.java:146)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.DefaultFontConfig$ParserHelper.parse(DefaultFontConfig.java:113)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.DefaultFontConfig$ParserHelper.<init>(DefaultFontConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.DefaultFontConfig$ParserHelper.<init>(DefaultFontConfig.java:84)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.DefaultFontConfig$DefaultFontConfigParser.parse(DefaultFontConfig.java:74)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFRendererConfig$ParserHelper.<init>(PDFRendererConfig.java:126)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFRendererConfig$ParserHelper.<init>(PDFRendererConfig.java:109)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFRendererConfig$PDFRendererConfigParser.build(PDFRendererConfig.java:101)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFRendererConfig$PDFRendererConfigParser.build(PDFRendererConfig.java:97)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.getRendererConfig(FopFactory.java:310)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent.getRendererConfig(FOUserAgent.java:663)
    at org.apache.fop.render.PrintRendererConfigurator.getRendererConfig(PrintRendererConfigurator.java:91)
    at org.apache.fop.render.PrintRendererConfigurator.getRendererConfig(PrintRendererConfigurator.java:80)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFRendererConfigurator.configure(PDFRendererConfigurator.java:45)
Wrapped by: org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: font without font-triplet
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.getRendererConfig(FopFactory.java:313)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent.getRendererConfig(FOUserAgent.java:663)
    at org.apache.fop.render.PrintRendererConfigurator.getRendererConfig(PrintRendererConfigurator.java:91)
    at org.apache.fop.render.PrintRendererConfigurator.getRendererConfig(PrintRendererConfigurator.java:80)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFRendererConfigurator.configure(PDFRendererConfigurator.java:45)
    at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.createDocumentHandler(RendererFactory.java:397)
    at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.tryIFDocumentHandlerMaker(RendererFactory.java:297)
```

I have configured font triplets:

```
        <font embed-url="classpath:/fop/static/fonts/arial.ttf">
          <font-triplet style="normal" name="Arial" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
        <font embed-url="classpath:/fop/static/fonts/arialbd.ttf">
          <font-triplet style="normal" name="Arial" weight="bold"/>
        </font>
        .........
```

This issue is happening randomly most of the time PDF is generated successfully. Error is not specific for which font its not able to find font-triplet.

Comment: Do you have any `<directory>/path/to/folder<directory>` or `<auto-detect/>` element in your configuration? If that's the case, there could be an unusual font in the folder that FOP cannot configure automatically, and the error would pop up only when the [font cache](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.9/fonts.html#font-cache) is built.

Comment: I dont have <auto-detect/> in project,  directory folder exist in pom.xml. <build> <resources><directory>src/main/resources</directory>...